# Boolean Algebra - is this statement correct?

Tags: boolean-algebra

So I have a statement that goes like this:

$$
( \lnot A \lor B) \land(\lnot A \lor \lnot B)
$$

I think it is equivalent to

$$
\lnot A
$$

Am I right or not?

Comment: Please explain your reasoning for why you think it is right.

Comment: It cannot be $B \land \lnot B$ at the same time while that is an error, so only think that is left is $\lnot A$

Comment: Yes. Whether $B$ is true or false has no bearing on the output. So we can eliminate the variable $B$ from all clauses. We are left with only $\neg A \land \neg A$ which is equivalent to $\neg A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it's a bit overkill for this problem, since there are only two variables, you can easily solve this with a truth table:

| A | B | $\lnot A$ | $( \lnot A \lor B) \land(\lnot A \lor \lnot B)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | False | False |
| True | False | False | False |
| False | True | True | True |
| False | False | True | True |

As you fill in the last column, you can quickly realize that the truth value of B has no impact on the truth value of the expression $( \lnot A \lor B) \land(\lnot A \lor \lnot B)$.

Answer (score 3):

1. We have $(¬A∨B)∧(¬A∨¬B)$
2. Realize that, by using the distributive law that is $p∨(q∧r)≡(p∨q)∧(p∨r)$, $-A∨(B∧¬B)$ is logically equivalent to$(¬A∨B)∧(¬A∨¬B)$. Let's have the simpler equivalent: $¬A∧(B∨¬B)$
3. Using negation law yields $¬A∧⊤$
4. Using identity law yields $¬A$

So, yes, you're right: $(¬A∨B)∧(¬A∨¬B)≡¬A$

Comment: What is $T$, is it "true"? What is $-$? How do you justify 2.? Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: yes, T means true. as for #2, it's the distributive law. i will edit my answer to make it more clear